# Importing STEP file into three.js / Converting STEP to STL in JS?

Tags: javascript, three.js, stl, converters, step

I'm trying to get STEP files running with three.js user friendly, which means: without converting externally into .stl format and without exporting as .stl for usage.

I'm searching a way to either convert .step files to .stl files internally within javascript while the user is uploading his .step file 
or
to directly use .step files with three.js.

I only found some converting examples with python([Converting a STEP file into an STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185998/converting-a-step-file-into-an-stl)), which i cannot use because of not knowing how and wanting to do it with JS and some others writing something about node-occ([import .step file with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103516/import-step-file-with-three-js)) which i don't even know exactly what it is...

If anyone could help me with that and can give me some tips I would be very happy.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import .step file with three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103516/import-step-file-with-three-js)

Comment: Another duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993597/how-to-load-step-stp-file-in-web-application-for-visualization-purpose

Comment: This helped me: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7125

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load .STEP / .STP file in web application for visualization purpose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49993597/how-to-load-step-stp-file-in-web-application-for-visualization-purpose)

Comment: For everyone still searching for a simple solution: I have already accepted that there is none long time ago. I have then implemented the functionality through a more complex preprocessing layer with a python script converting my uploaded step files into stl files with the free tool from FreeCAD at https://www.freecadweb.org/ before further using the stl files with threejs...